# ElasticSearch Aggregation Query to Select Top 1 for each Group base on Terms Array values

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, kibana, javabuilders

I have written below ES Query for fetching data Using filter and Must:
I can use only ElasticSearch V5 for writing queries.

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "term" : {
          "Name" : {
            "value" : "Self",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "filter" : [
      {
        "terms" : {
          "Number" : [
            "111",
            "222"
            
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am getting output Like this with Duplicate value. I want to use aggregate query.

```
 "hits": [
      { "Name": "Self","Number": 111},
      { "Name": "Self","Number": 222},
      { "Name": "Self","Number": 222},
      { "Name": "Self","Number": 111}
    ]
```

I want to select only Top 1 value for Each Number,So my Result out will be less.
O/P Should be:

```
"hits": [
          { "Name": "Self","Number": 222},
          { "Name": "Self","Number": 111}
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/collapse-search-results.html) to remove duplicate results

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "Name": {
              "value": "Self",
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "Number": [
              "111",
              "222"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "Number"
  }
}
```

Search Results will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "68849562",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "Name": "Self",
          "Number": 111
        },
        "fields": {
          "Number": [
            111
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "68849562",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.10536051,
        "_source": {
          "Name": "Self",
          "Number": 222
        },
        "fields": {
          "Number": [
            222
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Prashant Gupta please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Could you please help me with the Aggregation form of query to get  unique records ??

Comment: @PrashantGupta the search results shown above is it similar to what you expect to get ?

Comment: Yes, But I am not able to translate this query in java, it is not supporting in my Application

Comment: @PrashantGupta are you using Java high level rest client ?

Comment: yes but  it' s throwing Exception "URI template of the newly created target must not be null."

Comment: @PrashantGupta can you share the java code which you are using. That will help me to debug your issue in a much better way.